# Xcode C debugging changes values of pointers while stepping

Tags: c, llvm, xcode4.5, lldb

I am debugging a C code where I have a pointer inside a pointer to a struct named `board`. There is a function where I am printing the board:

```
static void board_print(board *b){
    int i,j;
    char data;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            data = b->data[i * size + j];
            if(data){
                printf("X ");
            }else{
                printf("O ");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Here is the weird part. When I hit my breakpoint initially at the beginning of first for loop, everything is OK, my data is correct, all the pointers work etc. as seen below:

[image: first]

Then, I step into the loop for the first time, with i and j equal to zero, and `b->data[0]` should be perfectly valid, as it was two steps ago. Suddenly, as soon as I step on the line `data = b->data[i * size + j];`, the data pointer changes into a null pointer. When I execute the line, I (obviously) get a bad access error, as seen below:

[image: second]

What could be the reason? I've used C before, and I've pretty got a grasp of it, but I've never seen a pointer value changing suddenly to null before while stepping in a single-threaded simple C program. I am using Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1 to compile and lldb to debug, which are the defaults with XCode 4.5.

**Update**: The same behavior observed with compiling with gcc and debugging with gdb. Almost hundred percent an arror at my side, but I have no idea what is wrong with the code..

**Update #2:** I've noticed something even stranger on gcc/gdb now. The just before executing the line `data = b->data[i * size + j];`, I can access everything from the debugger with no issues. Right after executing that line, I can't access `b->data` entirely, including the values that I've accessed right before stepping:

[image: third]

After the `$4 = ...` line which executed successfully in debugger, I've stepped over the line. Then I've got various addressing errors as see above. I really have no idea what's going on...

**Update #3:** I've noticed something very weird. Here, first look at the fix that I've implemented. This one started to work with no problem when I got rid of the variable named `data` completely:

[image: fourth]

Now, look closely at the screenshot that I've uploaded with the Update #2: Right after I assign a value to the *local variable* named `data`, also `b->data` gets its address changed. It looks like a side effect of the assignment. But I have no idea what is the reason behind it.

Comment: I don't think it'll be changed abruptly. Can you try to use another variable for the index and check? like `var = i * size + j;`  and check `b->data[var]` is indeed a valid pointer and `var` is not out of range and indeed what you calculated as the correct index?

Comment: Does the same error happen when you're not using the debugger?

Comment: found something: see my last update (3)

Comment: Your last update show a memory corruption... 

My theory : The board struct was in STACK memory, but not anymore and updating the local variable data is changing the content of the stack

Comment: i think I've found the problem. i was creating the board object on the stack without realizing it. it was hard to find the real cause, as the stack was (probably) changing somewhere unpredictably. and as a result, when the data at address of b was reallocated on the stack, the data pointer was changing into something, god knows where..

Comment: The stack WILL change as you are running through your function, so yes, that's perfectly reasonable effect.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu do you mean 'i was creating the board object on the stack without **initializing** it'? If  you can elaborate on your find would be great. For example what do you mean by 'when..b as **reallocated** on the stack'? I don't see any reallocation.

Comment: @zar it's been more than 3.5 years I honestly don't remember.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously something / somebody changes the property "data" of the board structure.

Why ? I can only see 3 reasons :

- Your application is multi-threaded and an other thread updates the data pointer to NULL (which is not your case, you are using only one thread, sorry didn't notice).
- The board structure is allocated from the stack but the content is not any more valid... For example : The pointer of a local variable is returned, but the variable (the struct) is destroyed (because this is a local variable) when returning the pointer...
- The board structure is allocated from the heap then freed, and finally this freed pointer is still used : the heap memory is corrupted by something else...

My guess : The second point which is a frequent mistake

So a simple question : The board struct is stored in HEAP or STACK memory ?

Comment: there is nothing related to multithreading in my code, it's a simple code. trust me, there is nothing to do with multithreading, as I've already stated clearly in the question.

Comment: @user93353 Sorry didn't see, I read the question a little bit to fast... I edited my answer. And sorry for my poor English...

Comment: yes, you were right. i was (by mistake) allocating the board on stack. see my last comment under the question.